# Alternate drivers with test-kitchen

Tags: chef-infra, test-kitchen

Many cookbooks, such as the [mysql cookbook](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/mysql) have multiple .kitchen.yml files.  For example, mysql has a .kitchen.yml and a .kitchen-cloud.yml.  Looking at documentation and code for test-kitchen, I can't see any way to use config files other than `.kitchen.yml`, `.kitchen.local.yml`, and `~/.kitchen/config.yml`.  If I wanted to use the cloud driver from the `mysql` cookbook, would I:

- `cp .kitchen-cloud.yml .kitchen.yml`
- `cp .kitchen-cloud.yml .kitchen.local.yml`
- something else??

It just seems like there should be a cleaner approach to using the alternative config file that a brute force replacement of the default ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Kitchen provides three environment variables to control where it looks for each of the possible configuration files.  To make the default behaviour explicit, you could set them as follows:

```
KITCHEN_YAML="./.kitchen.yml"
KITCHEN_LOCAL_YAML="./.kitchen.local.yml"
KITCHEN_GLOBAL_YAML="$HOME/.kitchen/config.yml"
```

You don't need to override all of them, so you could run test-kitchen with your `.kitchen-cloud.yml` like so:

```
$ KITCHEN_YAML=".kitchen-cloud.yml" kitchen test
```

Answer (score 13):

... to add to coderanger, if you want to select drivers or options based on whether your CI tool sets environment variables, you could also do something like this:

---

```
---
<%
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------
  # the driver_plugin can be overridden with an environment variable:
  #   $ KITCHEN_DRIVER=docker kitchen test
  # if not specified, defaults are used...
  #   - kitchen_driver_ci if environment variable CI=true or TRAVIS=true are present
  #   - kitchen_driver_local is used otherwise (which defaults to vagrant)
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------

  kitchen_driver_ci = 'ec2'
  kitchen_driver_local = 'vagrant'
  kitchen_driver_default = kitchen_driver_local

  if ENV['KITCHEN_DRIVER']
    kitchen_driver = ENV['KITCHEN_DRIVER']
  elsif ENV['TRAVIS']=="true"
    kitchen_driver = kitchen_driver_ci
  elsif ENV['CI']=="true"
    kitchen_driver = kitchen_driver_ci
  else
    kitchen_driver = kitchen_driver_default
  end
  puts "-----> driver_plugin: #{kitchen_driver.to_s}"    
%>

driver_plugin: <%= kitchen_driver %>
driver_config:
  require_chef_omnibus: 11.10.4
  <% if kitchen_driver == 'ec2' %>
  aws_access_key_id:      <%= ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'] %>
  aws_secret_access_key:  <%= ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'] %>
  aws_ssh_key_id:         <%= ENV['AWS_SSH_KEY_ID']         || "test-kitchen" %>
  ssh_key:                <%= ENV['AWS_SSH_KEY_FILE']       || "./test-kitchen.pem" %>
  region:                 <%= ENV['AWS_REGION']             || "us-east-1" %>
  availability_zone:      <%= ENV['AWS_AVAILABILITY_ZONE']  || "us-east-1c" %>
  flavor_id: "t2.small"
  groups: ["test-kitchen"]
  <% end %>
  <% if kitchen_driver == 'vagrant' %>
  customize:
    memory: 2048
  <% end %>

platforms:
- name: ubuntu-14.04
  <% if kitchen_driver == 'ec2' %>
  driver_config:
    image_id: ami-6ab2a702
    username: ubuntu
    tags: { "Name": "Test Kitchen" }
  <% end %>

busser:
  sudo: true

suites:
- name: default
  run_list: [
  ]
  attributes: {
  }
```

---

This way you maintain a single file and avoid divergent platform tests (making a change in one file and forgetting to in another). There are also cases where options provided in .kitchen.local.yml might conflict with those in .kitchen.yml.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to what zts said, remember that you can use ERb in kitchen files, so your driver config can look like this:

```
driver:
  name: <%= ENV['KITCHEN_DRIVER'] || 'vagrant' %>
```

Answer (score 5):

I found this Question while looking for a solution to supporting multiple drivers with one kitchen file and Ives's answer was very helpful. I adapted it to do the following.

- Default to the vagrant driver
- Allow the user to override the driver setting with a KITCHEN_DRIVER environment variable
- Select the docker_ssh driver if it is installed.

```erb
---
<%
require 'rubygems'
kitchen_driver = 'vagrant'

if ENV['KITCHEN_DRIVER']
    kitchen_driver = ENV['KITCHEN_DRIVER']
elsif Gem::Specification::find_all_by_name('kitchen-docker_ssh').any?
    kitchen_driver = 'docker_ssh'
end
%>

driver:
  name: <%= kitchen_driver %>
```